# Optimal legend placement after y-axis limiting

Tags: matplotlib, legend, axis, subplot

I've a fig with two subplots, I want them to have the same y-scale.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(10,6))

ax[0].set_title('Over Global region, {} points'. Format(len(df)))
ax[0].plot(df.groupby('type')['thickness'].mean(),label='Cloud mean thickness',color='red')
ax[0].set_xlabel('Cloud Type',fontsize=13)
ax[0].set_ylabel('(in km)',fontsize=15)
#Put xticks with labels at the bottom of the plot
ax[0].set_xticks(cloudlabel,cloudtype_dict.values(),rotation=50)

lon_left, lon_right, lat_bot, lat_top = 60, 100, 0, 40
dfcopy = df.copy()
dfcopy_aoi = dfcopy[(dfcopy['lon']>=lon_left) & (dfcopy['lon']<=lon_right) & (dfcopy['lat']>=lat_bot) & (dfcopy['lat']<=lat_top)]
ax[1].set_title('Over Indian subcontinent region, {} points'.format(len(dfcopy_aoi)))
ax[1].plot(dfcopy_aoi.groupby('type')['thickness'].mean(),label='Cloud mean thickness',color='red')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Cloud Type',fontsize=13)
ax[1].set_ylabel('(in km)',fontsize=15)
ax[1].set_xticks(cloudlabel,cloudtype_dict.values(),rotation=50);


#Shared y-axis
y_lim=[0,0]
y_lim = [min(ax[0].get_ylim()[0], ax[1].get_ylim()[0]), max(ax[0].get_ylim()[1], ax[1].get_ylim()[1])]
for i in range(2):
    ax[i].set_ylim(y_lim)
ax[0].legend(loc='best');
ax[1].legend(loc='best');
```

**Probelm**

I'm not getting the optimal legend placement for ax[0] even though I'm putting the legend argument at the end of everything.

Below is the image I am getting with bad legend loc for the first axis.

[image: bad legend misplacement photo]

Comment: Did you try `loc='upper center'`? Maybe it also overlaps?  A trick could be to place some dummy invisible element at the top left to force matplotlib not to put the legend there?  E.g. `plt.scatter(0, 14, color='none')`.

Comment: @JohanC That worked. I wanted to leave it to ```matplotlib``` to figure it out on its own. This position will work as I know that the shape won't change with different datasets.